# DECRYPTION of random text in C++

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I have a query about `DECRYPTION` of random text in C++, I already encrypted but in decrypted loop I'm stuck. I could not find solution.

Write a program that generates a random cipher for text messages. Each letter in the alphabet is substituted by 
another letter in a random manner. The program must be able both to encode and decode messages using the generated cipher.
The program must have the following features:

1. The program generates a cipher by replacing each Latin letter in the alphabet by one of the other letters, 
   based on the pseudo-random numbers generator. Two different letters cannot be replaced by the same letter.
2. The program reads a message in English from the standard input and encodes it using the random cipher. 
   The result is printed in the standard output.
3. The program reads a ciphered message from the standard input and decodes it using the same cipher. 
   Again, the result is printed in the standard output.

Code:

```
#include <iostream> //Basic standard input output library
#include <string> //header for using of data type string
#include <cstdlib> //Library header file, sand(), rand() prototypes
#include <ctime> //Library header file for measuring time, time() prototype
#include <cctype> //for character handling and classify and transform       individual characters

    using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(0)); //seed for rand, the program time (at execution of program) can make very nice seed values, because no two programs executions will occur at the same instant of the computers clock.
    static char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //static array to hold upper case letters
    static char alphabetlow[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //static array to hold lower case letter
    const int LENGTH = sizeof(alphabet, alphabetlow) - 1; // length of the array
    int r;
    char temp;
    char tempb;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) //loop which shuffle the array
    {
        r = rand() % LENGTH; //generate a sequance of pseudo-random numbers
        temp = alphabet[i]; //temp gets the initial value of the array element
        alphabet[i] = alphabet[r]; //randomized letters are copied into the ordered alphabet(now scrambled)
        alphabet[r] = temp; //ordered letters are copied into the scrambled alphabet

        tempb = alphabetlow[i]; //shuffle second array
        alphabetlow[i] = alphabetlow[r];
        alphabetlow[r] = tempb;
    }

    string text, textb;
    getline(cin, text);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) //loop to encrypt
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i])) //encrypt only input text which is latin letters
        {
            if (islower(text[i])) //checks if input text is lowercase letters
            {
                text[i] = alphabetlow[text[i] - 'a']; //scrambles lowercase letters
            } else {
                text[i] = alphabet[text[i] - 'A']; //scrambles uppercase letters
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Encrypted: " << text << endl;

    getline(cin, textb);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textb.length(); i++) //Loop for decoding
    {
        //Here i need help for decryption
    }

    cout << "Decrypted: " << textb << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: to decrypt a letter, you need to find its position in the scrambled alphabet, then figure out which letter would be at that position in the original alphabet.

Comment: how it could be possible because code is for random text, sorry i could not got you point exactly, can you please explain it more easiest way, because i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>//Basic standard input output library
using namespace std;
#include "EnDyc.h" // Include the header file of class

//EnDyc:: is used to access the members of this particular class

char EnDyc::alphabet[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";//static array to upper case letters
char EnDyc::alphabetlow[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";//static array to hold lower case letter
int EnDyc::LENGTH = sizeof(alphabet, alphabetlow) - 1;// length of the array};
void EnDyc::ran()
{
    srand(time(0));//seed for rand, the program time (at execution of program) can make very nice seed values, because no two programs executions will occur at the same instant of the computers clock.
    int r;
    char temp;
    char tempb;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) //loop which shuffle the array
    {
        r = rand() % LENGTH; //generate a sequance of pseudo-random numbers
        temp = alphabet[i];//temp gets the initial value of the array element
        alphabet[i] = alphabet[r];//randomized letters are copied into the ordered alphabet(now scrambled)
        alphabet[r] = temp;//ordered letters are copied into the scrambled alphabet

        tempb = alphabetlow[i];//shuffle second array
        alphabetlow[i] = alphabetlow[r];
        alphabetlow[r] = tempb;
    }

}




 string EnDyc::encyrp(string text)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)//loop to encrypt
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))//encrypt only input text which is latin letters
        {
            if (islower(text[i]))//checks if input text is lowercase letters
            {
                text[i] = alphabetlow[text[i] - 'a'];//scrambles lowercase letters
            }
            else
            {
                text[i] = alphabet[text[i] - 'A'];//scrambles uppercase letters
            }
        }
    }
    return text;// return the encrypted message to the main func
}



string EnDyc::decryp(string textb)
{
    //Dycription
    for (int i = 0; i < textb.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(textb[i]))//encrypt only input text which is latin letters
        {
            if (islower(textb[i]))//checks if input text is lowercase letters
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)//Loop for the Alphabets 0-25 in alphabet array
                {
                    if (textb[i] == alphabetlow[j])// check the location of input character
                    {
                        int ind = j + (int)'a';// Add the ASCI to the location of input character
                        textb[i] = (char)ind;//Convert the interger ASCI to character ASCI
                        break;// break the current execution
                    }
                }
                //scrambles lowercase letters
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)//Loop for the Alphabets 0-25 in alphabet array
                {
                    if (textb[i] == alphabet[j])// check the location of input character
                    {
                        int ind = j + (int)'A';// Add the ASCI to the location of input character
                        textb[i] = (char)ind;//Convert the interger ASCI to character ASCI
                        break;// break the current execution
                    }
                }
                //scrambles uppercase letters
            }
        }
    }
    return textb; // return the decrypted message to the main func

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef ENDYC_H

#include <iostream>//Basic standard input output library
#include <string>//header for using of data type string
#include <cstdlib>//Library header file, sand(), rand() prototypes
#include <ctime>//Library header file for measuring time, time() prototype
#include <cctype>//for character handling and classify and transform individual characters
using namespace std;
class EnDyc{// CLass for encryption and dycription
public:
static char alphabet[27];// An array to store lakin alphabets. In upper case
static char alphabetlow[27];// An array to store lakin alphabets. In lower case
static int LENGTH;// lenth of array for to ilplement loop for random arrangements of characters
static void ran();// method to  arrange alphabetic order randomly
static string encyrp(static string text);// method for the Encryption of message
static string decryp(static string textb);// method for the dycryption of message
};
#endif // !1
```

Comment: Adding some explanation about the code will help future users in understanding the answer better.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.